# To prove a collection is s topology

Tags: general-topology

I am stuck in the first step of the problem
 I am supposed to prove that $\{(-\infty, a)\times (-\infty,  b)\} $is a topology in the plane. But if it is the case, every (a,b) should be on the former set and  I can't find a way to get (a,b) as the kind of product is shown above.

Comment: Do you mean the collection of all sets of the form $(-\infty,a) \times (-\infty,b)$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$? This is not true, but they form the basis for a topology.

Comment: @kccu The fact that (a,b) cannot be that kind of product can be usef as an argument to prove is not a topology?

Comment: $(a,b)$ (in this context) would mean a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$, not an interval in $\mathbb{R}$. In any case, the topology defined by the basis consisting of sets of the form $(-\infty,a) \times (-\infty,b)$ need not be the same as the usual topology. So you can't conclude "it's not a topology" just because some open set in the usual topology is not in *this* topology.

Comment: @kccu I didn't mean the interval but the point in the plane $a \times b$

Comment: Well $(a,b) \in (-\infty,a+1) \times (-\infty,b+1)$...

Comment: @kccu I'm sorry I'm asking too many questions. From what I understand from the definition of topology, if the collection given defines a topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$ then $\mathbb{R}^2\subset T$, and to prove this I would show that every element of the plane $a\times b$ is of the form $(-\infty,x)\times (-\infty, y)$, if it were the case then $\mathbb{R}^2\subset T$, but if there is no $x,y$ such that $a\times b = (-\infty,x)\times (-\infty, y)$ then the condition $\mathbb{R}^2 \subset T$ cannot be satisfied. I don't know if this explain what I don't understan about the problem?

Comment: No, that is certainly not a requirement. It is required that $\mathbb{R}^2 \in T$, i.e., $\mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set in the topology. As I said, the collection of sets of the form $(-\infty,x) \times (-\infty,y)$ does not form a topology, as we can see $\mathbb{R}^2 \neq (-\infty,x) \times (\infty,y)$ for any $x,y$. But these sets still form a basis for a topology - we can take unions of them and obtain $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a topology $\scr T$ on $X$ must satisfy

1. Contains both $\emptyset$ and $X$
2. For any $U, V \in {\scr T}, ~U \cap V \in \scr T$
3. For any $\scr U \subseteq T, ~\bigcup U \in T$

If $\scr B$ satisfies at least condition (2), then it is called a basis for the topology $${\scr T} := \{ X\}\cup\left\{\bigcup \scr U\mid U \subseteq B\right\}$$

Now in your case, define $U(a,b) = (-\infty, a) \times (-\infty, b)$. Your collection of sets is ${\scr B} = \{U(a,b)\mid a,b \in \Bbb R\}$

It is easy to see that $U(a,b) \cap U(c,d) = U(\min\{a,c\}, \min\{b,d\})$, so $\scr B$ is a basis for a topology.

It is also clear that neither $\emptyset$ nor $\Bbb R^2$ is in $\scr B$, which disqualifies $\scr B$ from being a topology. But this is not satisfying because it would be easy to modify the definition to include them.

The real question is whether $\scr B$ is closed under unions. But this is easily seen to be false. For example $U(1,0) \cup U(0,1) \notin \scr B$.